# R Concatenate Across Rows Within Groups but Preserve Sequence

Tags: r, dplyr, concatenation, sequence

My data consists of text from many dyads that has been split into sentences, one per row.  I'd like to concatenate the data by speaker within dyads, essentially converting the data to speaking turns.  Here's an example data set:

```
dyad <- c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2)
speaker <- c("John", "John", "John", "Paul","John", "George", "Ringo", "Ringo", "George")
text <- c("Let's play",
          "We're wasting time",
          "Let's make a record!",
          "Let's work it out first",
          "Why?",
          "It goes like this",
          "Hold on",
          "Have to tighten my snare",
          "Ready?")

dat <- data.frame(dyad, speaker, text)
```

And this is what I'd like the data to look like:

```
  dyad speaker                                                text
1      1    John Let's play. We're wasting time. Let's make a record!
2      1    Paul                              Let's work it out first
3      1    John                                                 Why?
4      2  George                                    It goes like this
5      2   Ringo                    Hold on. Have to tighten my snare
6      2  George                                               Ready?
```

I've tried grouping by sender and pasting/collapsing from *dplyr* but the concatenation combines all of a sender's text without preserving speaking turn order. For example, John's last statement ("Why") winds up with his other text in the output rather than coming after Paul's comment. I also tried to check if the next speaker (using *lead(sender)*) is the same as current and then combining, but it only does adjacent rows, in which case it misses John's third comment in the example. Seems it should be simple but I can't make it happen.  And it should be flexible to combine any series of continuous rows by a given speaker.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create another group with `rleid` (from `data.table`) and `paste` the rows in `summarise`

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
library(stringr)
dat %>% 
   group_by(dyad, grp = rleid(speaker), speaker) %>% 
   summarise(text = str_c(text, collapse = ' '), .groups = 'drop') %>% 
   select(-grp)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 6 × 3
   dyad speaker text                                              
  <dbl> <chr>   <chr>                                             
1     1 John    Let's play We're wasting time Let's make a record!
2     1 Paul    Let's work it out first                           
3     1 John    Why?                                              
4     2 George  It goes like this                                 
5     2 Ringo   Hold on Have to tighten my snare                  
6     2 George  Ready?
```

Comment: Thanks, akrun, for your your quick and very helpful reply.  I had seen the *rleid* function in another post but didn't make the connection.  Breaking it down, it seems that *rleid* creates a new group column (named *grp* in your code) that ignores the repeated name within a dyad.  So the last comment by John in dyad gives John a new group number, different from what he was given in the first three lines.  I need to do a deep dive with *data.table*.

Answer (score 2):

Not as elegant as dear akrun's solution. `helper` does the same as `rleid` function here without the NO need of an additional package:

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>% 
  mutate(helper = (speaker != lag(speaker, 1, default = "xyz")),
         helper = cumsum(helper)) %>% 
  group_by(dyad, speaker, helper) %>% 
  summarise(text = paste0(text, collapse = " "), .groups = 'drop') %>% 
  select(-helper)
```

```
     dyad speaker text                                              
  <dbl> <chr>   <chr>                                             
1     1 John    Let's play We're wasting time Let's make a record!
2     1 John    Why?                                              
3     1 Paul    Let's work it out first                           
4     2 George  It goes like this                                 
5     2 George  Ready?                                            
6     2 Ringo   Hold on Have to tighten my snare
```

Comment: Thanks, TarJae.  That's a good option for dplyr.  I see what everything does except for *default="xyz"--the dplyr page defines the option as "value used for non-existent rows" but I'm not making the connection.  The lag look ahead assigned TRUE or FALSE to the new helper variable, so maybe "xyz" can be anything, a value that really won't be assigned to the new column?

Comment: default could be anything. xyz was just an example!

Comment: Thanks again, TarJae.  I should point out that your solution put's John's comment "Why" before Paul's, when it should be after.  See akrun's solution and my desired output.  The problem is fixed in your code by rearranging the *group_by* statement as follows: *group_by(dyad, helper, speaker)*